# Find html5 data attribute which matches the class of the element in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a side navigation menu whose the links look like this:

```
<div class="side_nav_feature_cont scrollElement" id="scrollE5">
<a class="pageScroller" data-scrollto="sec5">
    <span class="side_nav_feature_item">Develop and Nurture your Talent</span>  
    </a>
</div>
```

When they are clicked they scroll to a section with an anchor that looks like this:

```
<div class="sec5 sectionAnchor"></div>
```

That scrolling part of the script is working perfectly, but I would also like to add an active class to the side navigation item when it's halfway into the viewport. I am using the following script to check when the item is halfway, but I need to still "find" the matching "data-scrollto" based on the class of the anchor.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var halfWay = $(window).height()/2; // get half height of window
        $('.sectionAnchor').each(function() { // check each section anchor
            var distance = $(this).offset().top - halfWay; // check when halfway from top
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= distance) {
                // I want to find the matching data-scrollto here and add an active class
            }
        });
```

Is it possible to match the "sec5" from the class of the sectionAnchor to the data-scrollto "sec5" of the navigation item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this little jquery function, which just checks to see if the specified data attribute matches a given value.

```js
$.fn.filterByData = function (name, value) {
    return this.filter(function () {
        return $(this).data(name) === value;
    });
};
```

So, your code would look something like this, assuming the class that is in the data atttribute of the anchor tag is always the first class in the list:

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var halfWay = $(window).height() / 2; // get half height of window
    $('.sectionAnchor').each(function () { // check each section anchor
        var distance = $(this).offset().top - halfWay; // check when halfway from top
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= distance) {
            var classString = $(this).attr('class');
            if (classString) {
                //Get first class from class string
                var target = classString.split(' ')[0];
                //Find anchors and filter by data-scrollto == our class name
                var navItem = $('.pageScroller').filterByData('scrollto', target);

                navItem.addClass('active');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much for sharing. That works perfectly. [Here is my final code](http://pastebin.com/0n8qz7id) all put together including a scroll handling limit.  I started by removing any "active" class on scroll so there won't be multiple highlighted items and then add the matching element. Works great!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the match function to get the class from the sectionAnchor. Then get the correct menu option using the attribute selector.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var halfWay = $(window).height()/2; // get half height of window
        $('.sectionAnchor').each(function() { // check each section anchor
            var distance = $(this).offset().top - halfWay; // check when halfway from top
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= distance) {
                // I want to find the matching data-scrollto here and add an active class
                var id = $(this).attr('class').match(/(sec\d*)/)[0];
                $('a.pageScroller[data-scrollto="' + id + '"]').addClass('active');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! I implemented a different solution, but this looks it accomplishes the same thing.